# Notice: Undefined offset: 22 in C:\xampp\htdocs\authen.php on line 82

Tags: php, unset, notice

line numbber 82 is the if statement
 $re_arr is an array containing 25 elements

```
if ($pass[0]==substr($re_arr[$i],0,1))
{
    $pass1[0]=$re_arr[$i];
    unset($re_arr[$i]);
    $re_arr=array_values($re_arr);
}
```

what could be done to avoid the notice

Comment: @symbolicConstant what is wrong?? what rectification i need to do?

Comment: You have no such element in array: `$re_arr[$i]`. Check if `$i`-th element is defined.

Comment: its a part of the entire code $re_arr exists..else undefined index error would have occured

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a check if `$re_arr[$i]` exists.

```
if (!empty($re_arr[$i]) && $pass[0]==substr($re_arr[$i],0,1))
{
    $pass1[0]=$re_arr[$i];
    unset($re_arr[$i]);
    $re_arr=array_values($re_arr);
}
```

Comment: people are in hassle to do so...it worked for me thank you..i Will mark the answer accepted..

Comment: @AzraMahrukh Welcome... Yes it happens.. Nothing to do with that. :)